# Unable to insert NULL in date field for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert NULL to mysql from PHP using mysqli_query.

My code is as follows where I want to insert Null in `$chq_date`:

```
 $query_string = "INSERT INTO inward_credit
     (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_date, cheque_no)
     VALUES
     ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', '$chq_date', '$cheque_number')";

     $insert_credit = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
```

I tried

```
$chq_date = "";
```

which resulted in Incorrect date value: '' for column 'cheque_date' at row 1

```
$chq_date = '';
```

which resulted in Incorrect date value: '' for column 'cheque_date' at row 1

```
$chq_date = 'NULL';
```

Incorrect date value: 'NULL' for column 'cheque_date' at row 1

```
$chq_date = "NULL";
```

Incorrect date value: 'NULL' for column 'cheque_date' at row 1

The DB is as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inward_credit` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `custi_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `today_date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` float(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `mode` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `cheque_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cheque_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'cheque_date' at row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for your column is `NULL`, so it doesn't have to be in your `INSERT` statement.

```
$query_string = "INSERT INTO inward_credit
     (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_no)
     VALUES
     ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', '$cheque_number')";

     $insert_credit = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
```

#### Edit

If you are wanting to insert `NULL`, use the following;

- Don't quote the variable `$chq_date`, as that will make `NULL` a string. See [Marc B's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749436/3000179)

```
//if/else logic.
if(<<what>>) {
  $chq_date = "2014/09/09";
} else {
  $chq_date = "NULL";
}

$query_string = "INSERT INTO inward_credit
     (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_date, cheque_no)
     VALUES
     ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', $chq_date, '$cheque_number')";

     $insert_credit = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
```

Comment: Actually I have $chq_date as a date. I put in if statement like this:`if ($chq_date){
  $timestamp1 = strtotime($chq_date);
  $chq_date = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp1 );
  } else {
   $chq_date = NULL;
  }`

Comment: Now I get error as "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '')' at line 4"

Answer (score 2):

You're not inserting a null, you're inserting a STRING with the chars `N`, `U`, etc... in it:

```
$null_val = 'NULL';
$sql = "INSERT .... VALUES ('$null_val')";
                            ^---------^----
```

Since the above indicated quotes are always present, you'll NEVER be able to insert an actual sql null. Removing the quotes allows your string null to be SEEN as an sql null by the DB's parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NULL` without quotes:

```
$query_string = 
"INSERT INTO inward_credit (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_date, cheque_no)
 VALUES ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', $chq_date, '$cheque_number')"
```

Also, in your tale definition `DEFAULT NULL` is redundant (NULL is default in sql, hence you must specified NOT NULL when you don't want NULLs).

Answer (score 0):

In your table you have a default value as NULL. So no need to insert that

```
 $query_string = "INSERT INTO inward_credit
     (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_no)
     VALUES
     ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', '$cheque_number')";

     $insert_credit = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
```

But if you want to explicitly insert null you can try

```
$query_string = "INSERT INTO inward_credit
     (custi_id_fk, driver_id_fk, today_date, amount, mode, cheque_date, cheque_no)
     VALUES
     ('$cust_id1', '$driver_id1', '$today_date', '$credit_collected', '$mode', NULL, '$cheque_number')";

     $insert_credit = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
```